# Align element on bottom of div with dynamic border (absolute position + margin)

Tags: html, css

I´m currently trying to make an element with variable width and a border at it´s right. The border should always stay away a certain distance from the text elements, which vary in size and count. So the Border should move dynamically. It all works fine if I place my text elements inside the dynamic div but the text has to be positioned on the bottom of the page. So I tried to use `position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0;`. But I learned due to the absolute positioning `margin` won´t work any further.

You can find my code [here on codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqKZqV). The current state is the working dynamic border but with the text on the top side. I commented out the non working parts, which you can find on the bottom of the CSS file.

**So what is a better/working way to position my text on the bottom of my div but also have a dynamic border on the right ?**

```css
.statusbar {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 50vw;
  background: #303030;
  color: white;
}
.statusbar .statusbar-content {
  width: calc(100vw - 48px);
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 48px;
  float: left;
}
.statusbar .statusbar-content .statusbar-col {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #505050;
  position: relative;
  height: 110px;
}
.statusbar .statusbar-content #appserver-col,
.statusbar .statusbar-content #command-col,
.statusbar .statusbar-content #connection-col {
  margin-left: 23px;
}
.statusbar .statusbar-content #connection-col {
  border: none;
}
.statusbar .statusbar-content .col-content {
  padding-right: 23px;
}
.statusbar .statusbar-content .content-row {
  position: relative;
  height: 110px;
}
.statusbar .statusbar-content .content-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="statusbar">
  <div class="statusbar-content">
    <div class="statusbar-col" id="database-col">
      <div class="col-content">
        <div class="content-row">
          <div class="content-item">Test_Text_1</div>
          <div class="content-item">Test_Text_2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

**EDIT**

The output should look like this in the end.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works :

**HTML**

```
<div class="statusbar">
    <div class="statusbar-content">
        <div class="statusbar-col" id="database-col">
            <div class="col-content">
                <div class="content-row">
                    <div class="content-extender"></div>
                    <div class="content-item">Test_Text_1</div>
                    <div class="content-item">Test_Text_2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col-content {
    padding-right: 23px;
}

.content-row .content-extender {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 110px;
}

.content-item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 23px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

You don't specify an height on your `content-row`, but you extend vertically this container using an invisible (beacause empty) inline-block div. Then you align the inline-block components on bottom.

See here the forked codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONLpOw (I added something so you don't have to specify a fixed height on every block : the `content-extender` height defines the height of the overall statusbar).

Is that what you were trying to do ?

Comment: Yeah this is what I was trying to do. Works out for me. Can you maybe also tell me how to position another div or span above the `content-row` div with some pixel space between ?

Comment: Here I don't see the output you want to obtain...Do you want this new element to appear some pixels above the text ? or some pixels above the `content-row` block ?

Comment: I changed your answer in a minor way but i got the main idea behind your answer. It should be above the 'content-row'-block

Comment: Then, you just put it before the `content-row` block in your HTML (see the codepen in my answer I just edited).

Comment: Thanks for your extra effort but how can I set an exact space of numerous pixels between the `content-row` and the "extra" div on top ?

Comment: With margin-bottom on the extra div, for example (I updated the codepen. I added yellow dashed border so you can see where the blocks really are).

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that:

```
.statusbar .statusbar-content .content-row {
  position: relative;
  height: 110px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```css
.statusbar {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 50vw;
  background: #303030;
  color: white;
}
.statusbar .statusbar-content {
  width: calc(100vw - 48px);
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 48px;
  float: left;
}
.statusbar .statusbar-content .statusbar-col {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #505050;
  position: relative;
  height: 110px;
}
.statusbar .statusbar-content #appserver-col,
.statusbar .statusbar-content #command-col,
.statusbar .statusbar-content #connection-col {
  margin-left: 23px;
}
.statusbar .statusbar-content #connection-col {
  border: none;
}
.statusbar .statusbar-content .col-content {
  padding-right: 23px;
}
.statusbar .statusbar-content .content-row {
  position: relative;
  height: 110px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.statusbar .statusbar-content .content-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="statusbar">
  <div class="statusbar-content">
    <div class="statusbar-col" id="database-col">
      <div class="col-content">
        <div class="content-row">
          <div class="content-item">Test_Text_1</div>
          <div class="content-item">Test_Text_2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I really should have a look at flexbox some day !